# My express session isn't getting stored in cookies. What is wrong in my code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, redis

I'm trying to do a basic authentication page using google oauth2 using passportjs. When I click log in button, the session is getting updated to redis properly which I can see in a Redis GUI tool but when I check the session id in my redirected page, I'm getting a new session id everytime I reload as if the auth process hasn't done yet.

```
const express = require('express')
require('dotenv').config()
const app = express()
const session = require('express-session')
const passport = require('passport')
const sessionStore = require('./middlewares/redis.js')
const cors = require('cors')
const flash = require('connect-flash')

const paymentRouter = require('./middlewares/stripe.js')
const authRouter = require('./routes/auth')
const userRouter = require('./routes/users')
require('./config/db')

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3001',
    credentials: true,
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
  })
)

app.use(express.json())

app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'eureka',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: sessionStore,
    cookie: {
      secure: true,
      sameSite: 'none',
      httpOnly: false,
      maxAge: 600000,
    },
    proxy: true,
  })
)

app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
app.use(flash())
app.use('/auth', authRouter)
app.use('/users', userRouter)
app.use('/membership', paymentRouter)

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on port 3000')
})
```

I put out a console.log() in the google callback function this is what i got. I can clearly see that the user object is correctly stored

```
[0] google callback, req.session: Session {
[0]   cookie: {
[0]     path: '/',
[0]     _expires: 2023-05-09T19:35:43.013Z,
[0]     originalMaxAge: 600000,
[0]     httpOnly: false,
[0]     secure: true,
[0]     sameSite: 'none'
[0]   },
[0]   passport: { user: '6458c3cd6410491384c3584e' }
[0] }
```

After the login process it just disappears

```
[0] Session id in Redis: yCH5HVLwjSkQqd7wazHX5OJLx-bRMxLx
[0] req.session: Session {
[0]   cookie: {
[0]     path: '/',
[0]     _expires: 2023-05-09T19:35:45.505Z,
[0]     originalMaxAge: 600000,
[0]     httpOnly: false,
[0]     secure: true,
[0]     sameSite: 'none'
[0]   }
[0] }
```

adding my auth code

```
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback',
      passReqToCallback: true,
    },
    async function (req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
      const email = profile.emails[0].value
      const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email: email })
      console.log('user session', req.session)
      if (existingUser) {
        existingUser.googleId = profile.id
        await existingUser.save()
        return cb(null, existingUser)
      } else {
        const newUser = new User({
          email: email,
          googleId: profile.id,
        })
        console.log('new user:', newUser)
        await newUser.save()
        return cb(null, newUser)
      }
    }
  )
)

router.get(
  '/google',
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['email', 'profile'] })
)

router.get(
  '/google/callback',
  passport.authenticate('google', {
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: true,
  }),
  async function (req, res) {
    console.log('google callback, req.user:', req.user)
    console.log('google callback, req.session:', req.session)
    if (req.user) {
      req.flash('error', 'You are already logged in')
      req.session.save(() => {
        return res.redirect('http://localhost:3001/membership')
      })
    } else {
      req.session.save(() => {
        return res.redirect('http://localhost:3001/membership')
      })
    }
  }
)
```

What could be the problem? Im just stuck for the past 3 days and I tried most of the solutions in the forums but I still cant able to find a solution for this